# Related to AsyncTask in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm beginner to android. I have made the following app which takes time from user and sleeps for that time and during sleep shows a progress dialog. Now the problem is it works correctly for the first time but, it crashes on second one. Launching again gives same problem.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.asynctask;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    AsyncTaskExecutor executor;
    EditText text;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor();
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        executor.execute(text.getText().toString());
                    }
                 }
        );
    }

    class AsyncTaskExecutor extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>   {

        String res;
        ProgressDialog pd;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
            pd.setMessage("Sleeping..");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setTitle("Please wait");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(time);
                res = "successfull";
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                res = e.getMessage();
            }
            publishProgress(res);
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... a){
            pd.setMessage(a[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

Help required.

Comment: @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor();
                        executor.execute(text.getText().toString());
                    }

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: put this line executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor(); inside button click and before executor.execute(text.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the google document

[AsyncTask Threading rules :](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

so you have to create new object each time

```
 button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor(); 
                    executor.execute(text.getText().toString());
                }
             }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution

Remove this line---

> executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor();

And add inside button clicked as below.

```
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor();
                    executor.execute(text.getText().toString());
                }
             }
    );
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score -1):

If you use **executor.execute()** method and your android version is **>=HONEYCOMB** than its upto the android system when to start the **AsyncTask**. So this is the problem. To force execute the **Asynctask** you have to implement like this below.

```
executor = new AsyncTaskExecutor();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            executor.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            executor.execute();
        }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: THis isn't quite right.  On Honeycomb+ (and on 1.6-), all async tasks are done on a single thread.  A new one cannot be started until all previous ones have finished.  So its not that the system puts it off, its that another one is already running.  But this is an asynchronous task-  if your code depends on it starting right away, you have a race condition anyway.  You never know when the underlying Linux OS will actually run the new thread relative to the old.

Comment: ALso, that isn't his problem.  His problem is that an async task can only be executed once per instance.

Comment: Order of execution:  

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.  Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html